# How to add a pre-push git hook to an existing repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, githooks

I have a repository that I created with `git version 1.7.12`.

However, I have updated to `version 1.8.2.3`. This has the hook pre-push. Newly created repositories with this version use the pre-push hook. However when I add the pre-push to an existing repo, I get the following `error`:

```
fatal: cannot exec '.git/hooks/pre-push': Not a directory
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: I just made a new repository and the `pre-push.sample` file doesn't have execute permissions.  Maybe that's what's getting you?

Comment: Thanks! How would i fix that? @CarlNorum

Comment: I just did some more testing, it's likely that's what's getting you.  Writing an answer now.

Comment: I ran the line `chmod +x pre-push` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made a brand new repository, and the `pre-push.sample` is there, as you say.  It for some reason doesn't have execute permission set, though, so it doesn't work when renamed to `pre-push`.  If you add execute permission:

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-push
```

You should be ok.  The provided sample had a bash if/then bug too.  Changing line 32 from:

```
# Handle delete
```

to:

```
: # Handle delete
```

fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes it works on brand new repositories. But my question is how do you add a pre-push hook to an existing repository made from an older git version. It doesn't work when I create the file and run the `chmod` command. It gives me that error above.

Comment: Hm, I tried here and it seems to work fine.  I have 1.8.3, though.  Maybe it's a message from your script, rather than from git?  Can you show the script's contents?

Answer (score 0):

run "git init" to re-initialize your local git repository.